# std::string addition to char*

Tags: c++, stdstring

I'm trying to understand how addition of std::string to char* works.
This code is compiling and working just as expected:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

void func (const char* str) {
  printf("%s\n", str);
}

int main () {
  char arr[] = {'a','b','c',0};
  char *str = arr;
  func((str + std::string("xyz")).c_str()); // THIS LINE
  return 0;
}
```

But I do not understand what constructors/methods is calling and in what order for this to work. This is addition of std::string to char* which gives another std::string, but char* is not a class and it does not have a addition operator.

Comment: `std::string` has an overloaded `operator+` which accepts `char*` on left hand side. The result is `std::string`. (Hence, the `.c_str()` is needed.) Extra info: The lifetime of the temporary result of addition is long enough to finalize the call (without access to lost `std::string`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `operator +` for `const char*` on the left hand side and a temporary `std::string` on the right hand side. This is overload #4 [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B):

> ```
> template< class CharT, class Traits, class Alloc >
> basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>
>     operator+( const CharT* lhs,
>                const basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>& rhs );
> ```
>
> **Return value**
>
> A string containing characters from lhs followed by the characters from rhs

With `std::string` and `char`, the above template signature can be "interpreted" as

```
std::string operator+ (const char* lhs, const std::string& rhs);
```

The result is a new, temporary `std::string` object that owns the concatenated new buffer `"abcxyz"`. It can bind to the function argument of type `const char*` and is valid as long as the function body executes.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
str + std::string("xyz")
```

calls following operator:

```
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B

template< class CharT, class Traits, class Alloc >
    basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>
        operator+(const CharT* lhs,
                  basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>&& rhs );
```

and creates a temporary `std::string` (valid till the end of full statement) on which you call `.c_str()` which return `const char*` which is passed to the function.